# Flutter Blue Read Characteristics on Successful Connect

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

How do I listen to the response from my Arduino device on a successful connection?

Once connected, my Arduino devices send a list of values in this format [1111111111111111111111111111111111234].

But When I used Flutter Blue Package to read the characteristics, I was getting values like [45, 27, 8, 9], [0, 0], [0], [80, 45, 0, 2, 40].
When I converted these values with Utf8Decoder, it returned the name of the Bluetooth Device to me.

Below is my code I have tried

```
void dataReceived(Uint8List data){
if (data != null && data.length > 0) {

  updatedValue.add(data);
  print('data received $updatedValue');

  if (finalData.isNotEmpty) finalData.clear();
  print('final Data Empty $finalData');
}

print(' updated value: $updatedValue');

for (var i = 0; i < updatedValue.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < updatedValue[i].length; j++) {
    finalData.add(updatedValue[i][j]);
  }
}

print('final data $finalData');

String signals = Utf8Decoder().convert(finalData);

String binary = converter.toBinary(signals);
print("Binary: $binary");

print('signals: $signals');

    }
```

**NOTE: I have used BLUETOOTH SERIAL TO CONNECT AND IT GIVES ME CORRECT VALUES ARDUINO SENDS AFTER CONNECTION, BUT I'M NOW USING FLUTTER BLUE BECAUSE OF COMPATIBILITY WITH IOS**

I need the correct values/signals that arduino sends after connection with flutter blue package, suggestion and code on how to do this, I have been on it for days now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the values that you are receiving from flutter_blue are a list of int. which can be converted to string using `String.fromCharCodes`

```
List<int> response = const [34, 35, 36];
print(String.fromCharCodes(response));
```

After you read connect to the device try this code

```
var characteristics = service.characteristics;
for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
    List<int> value = await c.read();
    print(value);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still didn't work. This is the value I got from flutter_blue [82, 83, 72, 49, 48, 50]. Then, when I tried using  print(String.fromCharCodes(response)); It returned back to me the name of the Blueetoth device I am connected to.

Comment: Can you include the current code you are trying please?

Comment: print(String.fromCharCodes(finalData));

Comment: the code is exactly the one in the question body. So I just added your answer and passed in the finalData

Comment: Edited my answer to get characteristics from the device too

Comment: yes, these are screenshots of my code implementation. 
https://pasteboard.co/iQnb19UOA0eW.png,  https://pasteboard.co/n7hvvKsHbeRk.png,  https://pasteboard.co/ubhZdkaf3KWa.png

Comment: what was the output after getting characteristics? please edit your question with the findings so its easy to follow.

Comment: [82, 83, 72, 49, 48, 50] this is the output for the first characteristics

Comment: With these characteristics you can fetch services too

Comment: all the characteristics are under the services.                                                                      https://pasteboard.co/0v3QT6aS9Xzj.jpg

Comment: Try this  one. // Reads all characteristics
var characteristics = service.characteristics;
for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
    List<int> value = await c.read();
    print(value);
}

Comment: alright, will try it, thanks

Comment: I tried that method, but print(String.fromCharCodes(response)); returns nothing

Comment: Can you share your latest codes please?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/f2t6gATrJI88.png

Comment: Hi Kaushik Chandru, do you have another solution for us, we have tried you answer but no success, could this be flutter blue issue?

Comment: maybe if you are on any freelance platform like fiverr, you can send me you profile so i give you the task to do

Comment: You can download the example from flutter blue and test it. Sorry i am not on fiver

Answer (score 0):

Piece of code from the flow I use when using Flutter Blue after succesfully connected:

1. After connected (`snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected`)
2. Discover available services and characteristics from the connected device, something like

```
    BluetoothService mGattService;
    List<BluetoothService> gattServices;
    List<BluetoothCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics;
    String notifValue;

--------------------------------------------------------------

    // aftter connected
    gattServices = await widget.device.discoverServices();
    gattServices.forEach((service) {
      Guid currentServiceUid = service.uuid;

      mGattService = service;
        gattCharacteristics = mGattService.characteristics;
        gattCharacteristics.read().then((value) {
        notifValue = value.toString();
        print('Value from arduino = $notifValue');
      });
```

Comment: PS: Make use of each Guid provided by your arduino setup, for both Bluetooth Service and Bluetooth Characteristic

Answer (score 0):

this might help you in sucessfull connection
https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/blob/master/README.md

**Demo Code**

```
try {
    BluetoothConnection connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address);
    print('Connected to the device');

    connection.input.listen((Uint8List data) {
        print('Data incoming: ${ascii.decode(data)}');
        connection.output.add(data); // Sending data

        if (ascii.decode(data).contains('!')) {
            connection.finish(); // Closing connection
            print('Disconnecting by local host');
        }
    }).onDone(() {
        print('Disconnected by remote request');
    });
}
catch (exception) {
    print('Cannot connect, exception occured');
}
```